# Prove that, for each $n$, $\int^{1}_{0} f_n(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, contest-math

**Problem:** Define $f: [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ by

$f(x)= 2x$ for $0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$

and $f(x) = -2x+2$ for $\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 1$

Let, $f_1(x)=f(x)$ and $f_{n}(x) = f(f_{n-1}(x))$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Prove that for all $n$ $\int^{1}_{0} f_n(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}$

My attempt: I think it won't be required to find an explicit formula for $f_{n}(x)$ because I found $f_{2}(x)$, itself is pretty complicated.

I found $f_{2}(x)= 2(2x)$ for $0 \leq x < \frac{1}{2^2}$

$f_{2}(x)= -2(2x)+2$ for $\frac{1}{2^2} \leq x < \frac{2}{2^2}$

$f_{2}(x)= -2(-2x+2)+2$ for $\frac{2}{2^2} \leq x < \frac{3}{2^2}$

$f_{2}(x)= 2(-2x+2)$ for $\frac{3}{2^2} \leq x \leq \frac{4}{2^2}$.

Also, I am guessing the following must be true ( as it is true for $n=2$),

$\int^{\frac{k+1}{2^n}}_{\frac{k}{2^n}} f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$.

I tried to prove the above using induction but i could not.

So, please help

Comment: Have you tried to draw the graph $y=f_n(x)$ for small $n$?  What do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate way to think about your function $f(x)$ is as:

Double the $x$ value. If it is less than 1 (i.e. $2x\leq1$ from $x\leq\frac12$) then leave it. If it is more than one then reflect it in the line $y=1$ (from second half being $2(1-x)$ ). So double your input and fold it down if its over 1.

Using this definition and having knowledge of the first case should let you prove your induction easily.

Here is graphs of the first few iterations to help you visualize it.

[image]